# symfony webpack-encore not compile in win7x64

Tags: symfony, yarnpkg, webpack-encore

> "C:\Program Files (x86)\Yarn\bin\yarn.cmd" add sass-loader node-sass --dev
>   yarn add v1.3.2
>   [1/4] Resolving packages...
>   [2/4] Fetching packages...
>   error fsevents@1.1.3: The platform "win32" is incompatible with this module.
>   info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/add for documentation about this command.
>   error Found incompatible module
>   Process finished with exit code 1 at 15:24:10.
>   Execution time: 22 799 ms.

.....

What a cause of this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for helps!

This problem solved, I install 'webpack' first in my project.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is in node_modules directory and this is the solution : https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/626

Comment: Yarn only msi file and install only into ProgFiles(x32) but not for x64 ?

Comment: yes it's only in programme files x86 ,
but firstable you need to install nodejs ,
and to verify tap : yarn -v in terminal

Comment: I install 'webpack' and css & js compiled.

Comment: congratulations , so close the subject to mark as the problem has been solved